# Stacking groups of boxplots one above the other, each line belongs to a specific group

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a data frame of 12 columns. Those 12 columns are divided to 3 different groups:

The first 4 columns are the "Gene_1" group, each column of those start with `Gene_1`. The second group are from column 5 to column 8, and this group of columns start with `Gene_2`. The last group of columns are from 9 to 12 and they start with `Gene_3`.

All of those columns are numeric and continuous:

```
'data.frame':   482 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ Gene_1_TL1: num  0.383 0.461 0.448 0.448 0.461 ...
 $ Gene_1_TL2: num  0.46 0.52 0.254 0.222 0.302 ...
 $ Gene_1_TL3: num  0.277 0.425 0.182 0.254 0.329 ...
 $ Gene_1_TL4: num  0.565 0.565 0.164 0.159 0.235 ...
 $ Gene_2_TL1: num  0.0779 0.2742 0.0718 0.0718 0.2742 ...
 $ Gene_2_TL2: num  0.0662 0.2586 0.0602 0.0603 0.1416 ...
 $ Gene_2_TL3: num  0.1442 0.1456 0.0984 0.0907 0.2854 ...
 $ Gene_2_TL4: num  0.1183 0.1992 0.0868 0.0653 0.2034 ...
 $ Gene_3_TL1: num  0.287 0.417 0.256 0.256 0.417 ...
 $ Gene_3_TL2: num  0.3 0.419 0.425 0.432 0.584 ...
 $ Gene_3_TL3: num  0.315 0.343 0.315 0.353 0.562 ...
 $ Gene_3_TL4: num  0.217 0.283 0.249 0.421 0.564 ...
```

I want to make a boxplot for each column, so that each group would be side by side, and different groups would be one above the other.

So the 4 boxplots for the first group, the `Gene_1` groups, would be side by side. Then below them the second group, and the third group below that.

So I would have 3 lines of boxplots. Each line has 4 boxplots. Each line for a specific group.

I tried this code but it gave me all of them side by side and the X-axis was a mess, it seems it used the rownames in the X-axis and that is not good.

#### My try:

```
df_melted <- reshape2::melt(df)

boxplot <- ggplot(df_melted, aes(x=variable, y=value)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(. ~ gsub("\\d", "", variable), scales = "free_y") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))

boxplot
```

#### data subset:

```
structure(list(Gene_1_TL1= c(0.382992297410965, 0.460950464010239, 
0.447804838418961, 0.447804838418961, 0.460950464010239, 0.447804838418961, 
0.369836807250977, 0.447804838418961, 0.369836807250977, 0.447804838418961
), Gene_1_TL2= c(0.460011065006256, 0.52004611492157, 0.253930300474167, 
0.222006008028984, 0.302200853824615, 0.485153168439865, 0.20485857129097, 
0.350892871618271, 0.331338971853256, 0.295754462480545), Gene_1_TL3= c(0.277256995439529, 
0.425392180681229, 0.182383552193642, 0.253527283668518, 0.329186052083969, 
0.305586904287338, 0.188975885510445, 0.238625407218933, 0.497761845588684, 
0.342641144990921), Gene_1_TL4= c(0.565486133098602, 
0.564990341663361, 0.164183273911476, 0.15946152806282, 0.234778091311455, 
0.396436214447021, 0.172556579113007, 0.257463246583939, 0.43759897351265, 
0.200696632266045), Gene_2_TL1= c(0.0779446139931679, 0.274154871702194, 
0.0718425810337067, 0.0718425810337067, 0.274154871702194, 0.0718425810337067, 
0.160841777920723, 0.0718425810337067, 0.160841777920723, 0.0718425810337067
), Gene_2_TL2= c(0.0662130266427994, 0.258626192808151, 0.0601647943258286, 
0.060332003980875, 0.141631454229355, 0.113691322505474, 0.0786028951406479, 
0.0668068528175354, 0.171470999717712, 0.0754544585943222), Gene_2_TL3= c(0.144175127148628, 
0.145591989159584, 0.0984272509813309, 0.0906868129968643, 0.28544145822525, 
0.138114541769028, 0.091837003827095, 0.0904595032334328, 0.211963757872581, 
0.163982316851616), Gene_2_TL4= c(0.118267595767975, 
0.199180424213409, 0.0867970511317253, 0.0653180256485939, 0.203389659523964, 
0.149213299155235, 0.126333728432655, 0.0975232273340225, 0.256154090166092, 
0.146669581532478), Gene_3_TL1= c(0.287342727184296, 0.417357206344604, 
0.255898356437683, 0.255898356437683, 0.417357206344604, 0.255898356437683, 
0.471998482942581, 0.255898356437683, 0.471998482942581, 0.255898356437683
), Gene_3_TL2= c(0.299634903669357, 0.418549239635468, 0.424916654825211, 
0.432371437549591, 0.584436595439911, 0.296403467655182, 0.563782930374146, 
0.3688924908638, 0.578023612499237, 0.278784334659576), Gene_3_TL3= c(0.314525783061981, 
0.343217849731445, 0.315391361713409, 0.353350460529327, 0.562197327613831, 
0.292534917593002, 0.616392850875854, 0.284660279750824, 0.532478809356689, 
0.341239869594574), Gene_3_TL4= c(0.216887220740318, 
0.283130913972855, 0.248720198869705, 0.421182304620743, 0.564142644405365, 
0.204288363456726, 0.778401911258698, 0.272624760866165, 0.511143803596497, 
0.186424404382706)), row.names = c("04d83340b8bd", "122T", "1c2a5ac94492", 
"1d209304d988", "212T", "24ab7fecc92e", "356T", "379fe8924c51", 
"39T", "3ec4d3fc8bd1"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to split your variable in two parts, i.e. the gene or `group` and the `variable`s. This could for example be achieved using `tidyr::pivot_longer` instead of `reshape2::melt`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

df_melted <- df |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(everything(),
    names_to = c("group", "variable"),
    names_pattern = "^(Gene_\\d)_(.*)$"
  )

ggplot(df_melted, aes(x = variable, y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~group, scales = "free_y", ncol = 1) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")
  )
```

[image]